# How to ignore year in DateListPlot

Tags: plotting, curated-data, date-and-time

I just upgraded to *Mathematica* 10, and I am trying to get the hang of the new `TimeSeries` data objects, which are preventing my old strategy of overlaying data from different years on the same plot. As an example, comparing temperatures from different years:

```
d2014 = WeatherData["KMSP", "MeanTemperature", {{2014, 9}, {2014, 12}, "Day"}];
d2015 = WeatherData["KDAY", "MeanTemperature", {{2015, 9}, {2015, 10}, "Day"}];
DateListPlot[{d2014, d2015}]
```

The above code results in the image below; in *Mathematica* 9 I could manually shift the year of one data set so two data sets from different years would overlay like I wanted.

[image: DateListPlot image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than messing with the internals, let *Mathematica* do the work for you. The function you are looking for is [`TimeSeriesShift`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesShift.html):

```
d2014 = WeatherData["KMSP", "MeanTemperature", {{2014, 9}, {2014, 12}, "Day"}];
d2015 = WeatherData["KDAY", "MeanTemperature", {{2015, 9}, {2015, 10}, "Day"}];
DateListPlot[{d2014, TimeSeriesShift[d2015, {-365, "Day"}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The advantage over changing things manually is the fact that you don't have to mess with date objects and so on: all the transformations are done transparently.

Comment: I agree, and I'm a bit embarrassed that I didn't come across the `TimeSeriesShift` function in the Documentation Center

Comment: Not all years have 365 days...

Comment: @user2705196 Sure, but neither 2014 nor 2015, the two years in the question, were leap years, so they were indeed 365 days long.

Comment: @MarcoB Absolutely true. I just commented because I ran into the same problem as the OP and used your elegant solution. And only at the very end I realized I was shifting things incorrectly for some of the years in my data set due to leap years. But TimeSeriesShift[myDATA, {-1, "Year"} worked beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's another method using `DateFunction` to change how the dates are interpreted by `DateListPlot`

```
DateListPlot[{d2014, d2015}, 
  DateFunction -> ({2015}~Join~DateValue[#, {"Month", "Day"}] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping that there was an option that could be passed to `DateListPlot` that would do the work for me. This is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
x1 = Normal @ d2014 /. {a_Integer, b_} :> {DateList[a][[1 ;; 3]], b};

x2 = Normal @ d2015 /. {a_Integer, b_} :> {DateList[a][[1 ;; 3]], b} /. (2015) -> 2014

DateListPlot[{x1, x2}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Mark you should not be so quick to mark something as accepted. There are other, less intrusive methods.

Comment: Actually you can omit `[[1 ;; 3]]`. I routinely use this to drop hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: And actually, some experimentation showed that I could omit the entire following section and get the same result:
`{a_Integer, b_} :> {DateList[a][[1 ;; 3]], b}`

Comment: @rcollyer I'm new to this, and my initial understanding was the first answer to solve the problem won the vote; my bad :S

Comment: @Mark in general, we recommend waiting a day before accepting an answer, just in case multiple answers are forthcoming. Note: you are always capable of switching who gets the checkmark. Since I'm one who might benefit from that, please don't take that as pressure to change it; I have plenty of reputation, already.